# Evaluation of $~\iint_{D} {x^2-y^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y~$ where $~D~$is of bounded and closed and line symmetric with $~y=x$

Tags: polar-coordinates, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

$~D:=$domain where it is bounded and closed in $~ \mathbb R^2 ~$ and line symmetric with $~ y=x ~$
$$
I:=\underbrace{\iint_{D} {x^2-y^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y}_{\text{I want to evaluate this double integral} } 
$$

I guess that $~D~$ is a domain of, for all $~(a,a)~$ on $~y=x~$,euclid distances between each boundary of $D_1,D_2$ and $y|_{x=a}=x|_{x=a}$ are same.

I've written the example of the domain $~D~$ as follwoing.

[image]

**ADDed**

As the advice from @Hans Lundmark says, seems at least, $I$ takes a constant value such as $0$ .

Comment: The formulation is quite unclear, but I suspect that you're supposed to show that for **any** domain $D$ which is bounded, closed and symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$, the integral is equal to zero.

Comment: Hint: show $\iint_D\frac{x^2\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{1+x^4+y^4}$ converges.

Comment: @J.G. It is difficult for me to prove it so far... Change-of-variables into polar coordinates system is required?

Comment: @J.G. I will convert it into polar system first.

Comment: That's overthinking it. Use the fact $D$ is bounded, together with e.g. $0\le\frac{x^2}{1+x^4+y^4}\le\min\{x^2,\,x^{-2}\}$.

Comment: I've gave up X0.

Comment: I did parts of the integral on paper and also tried putting into Wolfram alpha and either way got long expressions involving arctan and log for the first integral. It might be possible to do the second integral but I didn't get that far and Wolfram Alpha gave up too.

Answer (score 1):

$$
I:=\iint_{D} {x^2-y^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
$$
Swap the names $x$ and $y$ then
$$
I=\iint_{D} {y^2-x^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x
$$
Then notice that
$$
-I=\iint_{D} {x^2-y^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x
$$
Since the region $D$ is symmetric if $x$ and $y$ are actually swapped, we can swap the region of integration, so
$$
-I=\iint_{D} {x^2-y^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y=I
$$
so we have $-I=I$, the only solution of which is that $I=0$.

Intuitively, if the region $D$ is symmetric with respect to reflection in the line $y=x$, then for each $y^2-x^2$ in the integrand, we have an equivalent numerator $x^2-y^2$ with the same denominator on the other side of the line $y=x$ which cancels it out.

Another way to see this is to change variables to $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$. You then get an integral like
$$
\int_{R}\int_{-v_0}^{v_0} {uv\over 1+(u^2+v^2)^2/4-(u^2-v^2)^2/16}dv \;du
$$
which is an odd function of $v$, so you can see that it integrates to zero identically. Here we have the limits of integration from $-v_0$ to $v_0$ because our region of integration is symmetric around the line $y=x$. This is somewhat like rotating our "axes" by $45^\circ$ anticlockwise.

(Here $(u^2+v^2)^2=2(x^2+y^2)$ and $u^2-v^2=4xy$ so $4(u^2+v^2)^2-(u^2-v^2)^2=16(x^4+y^4)$.)

Comment: In the first place I can't understand why swapping $x$ and $y$ is permitted in the second line shown above...

Comment: That is just renaming $x$ and $y$. Perhaps if I had renamed them $a$ and $b$ or something it might make it easier to understand. The integral is exactly the same but the names of the variables are changed.

Comment: I see. In the firstly given double integral equation, I assume that equation is made with yx-axis where y-axis is vertical and x-axis is horizontal. So needless to say, as we swap variables in the second line, I assume that the axes are also renamed.

Comment: I think that I have too less ability to understand $~
-I=\iint_{D} {x^2-y^2 \over 1+x^4+y^4 } \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y=I
~$ for now.. I will be back in the future to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to give an intuitive explanation in the last paragraph. Perhaps if you read that last paragraph it might make sense. The function is antisymmetric over this region. It is something like $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin x dx=0$, it is zero because there is always a negative for every positive.